# Ubuntu 14.04 user cant CD into folder even though in group

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I've an Ubuntu 14.04 VPS running LAMP web server and all working OK. I've got a friend who needs a website hosting for a him and have set him up with  a virtual host and all is running fine.

I now want to give him FTP access to only his sites' public_html folder on the server.  I've created a user called 'james' and group called 'jamesftp' of which I've the 'james' user to.

I've then added the group 'jamesftp' as group owner of his 'public_html' folder in order grant him FTP access.  I'm logged in as the 'james' user in an SSH shell but it's not letting me CD to the folder?  Where I am going wrong?

ERROR MESSAGE WHEN LOGGED IN AS 'JAMES'

```
bash: cd: /var/www/***.com/public_html: Permission denied
```

PERMISSIONS ON FOLDER WHEN LOGGED IN AS ROOT

```
ls -la /var/www/***.com/public_html

drwxrwxr--  5 www-data jamesftp   4096 Dec  9 06:21 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data jamesftp   4096 Nov 20 07:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data jamesftp    236 Nov 26 08:52 .htaccess
-rwxr-xr--  1 www-data jamesftp    139 Nov 20 09:30 index.html
-rwxrwxr--  1 www-data jamesftp    418 Sep  2 23:33 index.php
-rwxrwxr--  1 www-data jamesftp  19930 Sep  2 23:33 license.txt
-rwxrwxr--  1 www-data jamesftp   7360 Sep 15 10:26 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data jamesftp 826942 Nov 25 03:36 tuid.sql
-rwxrwxr--  1 www-data jamesftp   4951 Sep  2 23:33 wp-activate.php
drwxrwxr--  9 www-data jamesftp   4096 Sep 15 10:58 wp-admin
-rwxrwxr--  1 www-data jamesftp    271 Sep  2 23:33 wp-blog-header.php
-rwxrwxr--  1 www-data jamesftp   5007 Sep  2 23:33 wp-comments-post.php
```

Comment: Can you do this one step at a time. E.g. if you are logged in as james can you then `cd /var`. And then `cd www`, `cd ***.com`. Etc etc. Maybe he has no `x` rights on one of the upper folders.

Comment: Ah right, got into 'var' OK but then denied at 'www'.  What now, add 'jamesftp' group to 'www'?

Comment: That could work. Or `chmod o+x` on  that www directory.

What you need to end up with is a full path to the destination folder with x rights. x is execute for binaries, but 'cd into' for directories.

Alternatively, you could configure the webserver to look for files in someones homedir. E.g. in /home/james/wwwfiles.  Which might actually be cleaner is james has his own domain.

Comment: Moving the website files to his home directory is actually a good idea, never thought of that!  Would you not envisage any permission problems with that?

Comment: My first webpage was one single file located in ~/.html/inex.html   
So I know it can work. I did configure that server though.